# Replacing <p></p> innerHTML with document.getElementById by using var

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, var, getelementbyid

I'm trying to replace the id `example` that has `<p> Hello! </p>` with `<p> Hi! </p>` using var.

This is what I tried:
`var i = Hi!`

`document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '<p>i</p>'`
but it changed `example` to `<p>i</p>`, not "Hi!"

Comment: `var i = Hi!` is invalid as `Hi!` is not a string, you need to wrap it in quotes. `<p>i</p>` did exactly what you told it to, check out string templates if that's a syntax you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for String concatenation. You originally surrounded the variable name with quotations, which causes it to be interpreted as a String.

```js
function go(){
    var i = "Hi!"
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "<p>"+i+"</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="example"><p>Test</p></div>
<button onclick="go()">Change</button>
```

Comment: @LazaroYT Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for  [template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var i = "Hi!";
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = `<p>${i}</p>`;
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <p>Hi there!</p>
</div>
```